# Avoid creating more than one edge between vertices (java.util, linkedList, Graph)

Tags: java

This code is creating a random "graph" with random edges, but in some occasions, this part of the code:

```
 for(int i=0;i<k;i++)     {

         int numero2 = (int) (Math.random() * k);
         int numero3 = (int) (Math.random() * k);

         g.addEdge(numero2, numero3 );

     }
```

does not avoid creating two or three edges between nodes, which is wrong, because it does not simulate a regular graph. What sort of condition should I add to the code, in order to completely avoid creating more than one edge between two vertices?

Thanks in advance. Specially if there is an answer or even better, a good answer to my question.

The complete code is:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;


class Graph{
    class Edge{
        int v;
        public Edge(int v){
            this.v=v;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return "("+v+")";
        }
    }
    List<Edge> G[];
    public Graph(int n){
        G=new LinkedList[n];
        for(int i=0;i<G.length;i++)
            G[i]=new LinkedList<Edge>();
    }

    void addEdge(int u,int v){
        G[u].add(0,new Edge(v)); 
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String result="";
        for(int i=0;i<G.length;i++)
            result+=i+"=>"+G[i]+"\n";
        return result;
    }


}

    public class Graph01 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int k = (int) (Math.random() * 5) + 5;          


     Graph g; 
     g = new Graph(k);

     for(int i=0;i<k;i++)     {

         int numero2 = (int) (Math.random() * k);
         int numero3 = (int) (Math.random() * k);

         g.addEdge(numero2, numero3 );

     }                                     


        System.out.println(g);


        }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but there exist graph libraries so you don't need to reinvent the wheel. For example [JGraphT](http://jgrapht.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three possibilities:

1. Generate a random edge; if that edge exists generate a different one; repeat until you have all the edges you want
2. Enumerate all the possible edges in advance; randomly select edges from this set, removing them from the set as you "use" them.
3. Iterate over all nodes, one at a time, generating `n` *outgoing* edges where `n` is to your liking.

In option 3, if your edges are not directed, or you want to avoid distance-1 cycles (A->B and B->A), the problem is a little more complex but still easily solvable.

None of these options generates graphs free of cycles with distance greater than 1.  Doing that will require more sophisticated coding.