# Accesing each linked list in a graph (java.util)

Tags: java

This is based on this thread of mine, and the same code: [Avoid creating more than one edge between vertices (java.util, linkedList, Graph)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45874824/avoid-creating-more-than-one-edge-between-vertices-java-util-linkedlist-graph) . I think that I am not understanding something important about linked lists, which is: I don't know how to access the arrays and items in a particular list of the several linked lists generated by the code.

In the Graph class there is this piece of code:

```
 List<Edge> G[];
    public Graph(int n){
        G=new LinkedList[n];
        for(int i=0;i<G.length;i++)
            G[i]=new LinkedList<Edge>();
    }

    void addEdge(int u,int v){
        G[u].add(0,new Edge(v)); 
    }
```

And in the main class, I can just do:

```
 Graph g; 
 g = new Graph(k);
```

As g is a Graph, and the graph is an array of linked lists, I thought it made sense to access each linked list using g[i]. But it is my wrong guess cause trying:

```
System.out.println(g[1]);
```

throws an error. How then, can I access each linked list? This would be helpful so that I could use the contain method (which is valid for linked lists) to verify if there exists a particular element in that Linkedlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`g` is an object of type `Graph` it's not an array and hence you can't access indices - simply because it has none.

Every instance of Graph, `g` does have a field: `List<Edge> G[]` but it shouldn't be accessed directly (otherwise it's breaking the encapsulation).